# Autocomplete dropdown list needs layout change

Tags: android, android-layout, autocomplete

I currently have an autocomplete dropdown box on my app, but it appears the font color is a sort of grey and not visible when the list is being populated. The second picture shows how the dropdown looks when clicked. How can I change the layout for the dropdown to show the items in the list as a different colour like black?

Pics below !

[image: First]

[image: Second]

## EDIT

```
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingsMain.this);
                LayoutInflater inflater =     SettingsMain.this.getLayoutInflater(); 
                final View searchlayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_friend, null);
               
                friend_name = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchlayout.findViewById(R.id.friend_name);       
                friend_name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                    }

                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

                    }

                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
                        String text = charSequence.toString();
                            
                            new MyAsyncTask("get").execute("http://10.0.2.2/jamtivia/webservice.php?type=get_friends&username="+text);
                            drop_down_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,adapterList);
                            drop_down_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            friend_name.setAdapter(drop_down_adapter);
                            if (!friend_name.isPopupShowing()) {
                                friend_name.showDropDown();
                            } 
                            
                            
                                for(int i =0;i < adapterList.size();i++)
                                    Log.d("TEXT CHNGE", adapterList.get(i));
                    }
                });
        
                adb.setView(searchlayout)
               
               .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {  
                        String fname = friend_name.getText().toString();
                        Integer friend_id = null;
                        
                        try{
                            friend_id = adapterListId.get(adapterList.indexOf(fname));
                            Log.d( "ECHO" , "text : " + name +"ID :"+ player_id+ " ID: " + friend_id);
                            String request = "http://10.0.2.2/jamtivia/webservice.php?type=add_friends&friendId="+friend_id+"&playerId="+player_id;
                            new MyAsyncTask("send").execute(request);
                        }catch(Exception e){Log.d( "PROBLEM SENDING" , "text : " + adapterList.indexOf(fname));}
                        return;                  
                       }  
                  })
               .setNegativeButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        dialog.cancel(); 
                    }
                }); 
    
                    adb.show();
```

Also, as far as you can see with this snippet of code, is this a good way to carry out this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating ArrayAdapter instead using the predefined layout use your custom layout

like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:id="@+id/cust_view"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/list_style" 
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
```

//you can give color or image of your choice as background
and give a name as your choice let us say custom_list.xml

While Creating adapter use your layout like this

```
 drop_down_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_list,adapterList);
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will check it out now

Comment: Working with my custom view for the drop down now, but I want scrolling ability for the drop down list and of course I cant put any scrollview in the adapter layout or I will get an error. How else can i get this drop down list to be in a scroll view?